# Where do my iPod's notes go when they're synchronized with my Gmail account?

Tags: data-synchronization, ipod, gmail, notes.app

Where do my iPod's notes go when they're synchronized with my Gmail account? Where can I find them in my browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you go to Gmail, you should now see a 'notes' label in gmail.

This will hold your notes, but you can not edit them in gmail.